# jqGrid "Loading..." overlay showing "undefined" though grid is working

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that's working 100% except that it keeps displaying "undefined" in the "Loading..." overlay.  I can't really figure it out.  It seems like I should only get the "undefined" message if something isn't set right and the grid would cease to work.  But that's not the case.  *scratches head*

I'm not really sure a code sample would help here, but if anyone would like to see a certain part of my code let me know and I'll included.

Has anyone else come across this issue before?  I'm probably missing something so simple and small that I can't see it.  So my apologies in advance if this is a no-brainer

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The easiest way to find the reason is posting the full code example which reproduces your problem. Then somebody can quickly find the bug.

Comment: I know Oleg , that somebody will be mostly you., which the question is regarding 'jqgrid' :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That text comes from `$.jgrid.defaults.loadtext`. So either:

1. You have an old `grid.locale-en.js` which doesn't specify it, or
2. You overwrite it somewhere.

Comment: I just verified that the grid.locale-en.js library is present and available.  I even updated all the i18n library files to my current jqGrid version.  No change.  Suggestions?

Comment: Debug through grid.base.js in the `jqGrid` call when the defaults are merged with the user options. Watch `loadtext` in the merged options.

Comment: I finally go this working.  I don't know how I missed it but I hadn't included the /i18n/grid.locale-en.js library in my script.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, I've found that the `<script>` tag that defines `grid.locale`-whatever must appear before the `<script>` tag that loads `jqgrid`.

Doesn't make sense to me.